# gvim "open in new window" should change directory to the one of the current file

Tags: vim

I'm working in gvim with sessions and tabs, and everything works great. However there is something that is bothering me.

Say I have two files open: /A/B/foo.ext and /C/D/E/bar.ext, the latter being opened last. Now say I want to open /A/B/foobar.ext. I have to go through the hassle of navigating upwards to / and from there to /A/B.

I would like to simply change my active tab to /A/B/foo.ext and have gvim automatically change its active directory to /A/B/, so that when I want to open /A/B/foobar.ext with /A/B/foo.ext being active, I'm already in the right CWD.

This would be very time-saving if you work with two different projects at a time and need to switch back and forth between the two.

Is there any such script that does just that?

Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, found it: `set autochdir`. It seems the directive was too early in my .vimrc and got overwritten by something else.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have this in my `.vimrc`:

```
if exists('+autochdir')
    set autochdir
else
    autocmd BufEnter * silent! lcd %:p:h:gs/ /\\ /
endif
```

As far as I remember, Vim has this option since v7.

HTH